# Margins not adjusted in par( )

Tags: r, par, r-corrplot

I am plotting several corrplots in one plot and want to plot the colorlegend underneath the plot, therefore I need to adjust the margins but somehow the margins are not adjusted, here is my code:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,3),mar=c(8,5,5,3))
corrplot(Cor_EC_3_eur,method="color",title = "\nCore/Energy 3M",mar=c(0,0,2,0),tl.col = "black",cl.pos="n",col=color1)
corrplot(Cor_FE_3_eur,method="color",title = "Eurozone \nFood/Energy 3M",mar=c(0,0,2,0),tl.col = "black",cl.pos="n",col=color1)
corrplot(Cor_CF_3_eur,method="color",title = "\nCore/Food 3M",mar=c(0,0,2,0),tl.col = "black",cl.pos="n",col=color1)
corrplot(Cor_EC_3_aus,method="color",title = "\nCore/Energy 3M",mar=c(0,0,2,0),tl.col = "black",cl.pos="n",col=color1)
corrplot(Cor_FE_3_aus,method="color",title = "Australia \nFood/Energy 3M",mar=c(0,0,2,0),tl.col = "black",cl.pos="n",col=color1)
corrplot(Cor_CF_3_aus,method="color",title = "\nCore/Food 3M",mar=c(0,0,2,0),tl.col = "black",cl.pos="n",col=color1)
corrplot(Cor_EC_3_sa,method="color",title = "\nCore/Energy 3M",mar=c(0,0,2,0),tl.col = "black",cl.pos="n",col=color1)
corrplot(Cor_FE_3_sa,method="color",title = "South Africa \nFood/Energy 3M",mar=c(0,0,2,0),tl.col = "black",cl.pos="n",col=color1)
colorlegend(xlim=c(-5,10), ylim=c(-1,0), color1, c(seq(-1,1,.25)), align="c", vertical=FALSE, addlabels=TRUE)
corrplot(Cor_CF_3_sa,method="color",title = "\nCore/Food 3M",mar=c(0,0,2,0),tl.col = "black",cl.pos="n",col=color1)
```

which results in following plot:

[Corrplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJKw4.png)

where the colorlegend is in the 3 row under the middle corrplot only as a straight line visible.

but want to have something like that (only that the colorlegend is downwards shifted):

[Corrplot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k09lo.png)

Thanks and best
Jakob

Comment: How can we reproduce this?

Comment: aren't you setting the margins with `mar=c(0,0,2,0)` which puts a margin at the top for the title I guess and then leaves 0 at the bottom  `c(bottom, left, top, right)` so there is no space left for the legend

Comment: also I edited to show the plot there seems to be one missing

Comment: sorry, now the plots are available

Comment: what if you use `xlim=c(0.5,12), ylim=c(-1,0)` in colorlegend and I would add the parameter names for color1 and c(seq(-1,1,.25)  such as col=color1 and labels=c(seq(-1,1,.25)  so that it is clearer